# Access JSON data from different server/domain using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to fetch JSON data/file from other server/domain.

My understanding is that from below code i should be able to see success alert but i see error alert

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "http://xxxx.com/zzzz",
                    dataType: 'jsonp', 
                    success: function (json) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
```

In firebug console i see this error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement


"responseHeader":{
```

If i open the URL in browser i can see JSON data but not able to fetch it and parse.

This is the starting part of the JSON data if i hit the URL in browser for reference

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4576,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "facet.limit":"10",
      "facet.field":["DataSet",
        "Site",
        "Year",
        "Product"],
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json",
      "facet":"true"}},
  "response":{"numFound":260682,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
```

Am i doing anything wrong here OR should i try differently to access JSON data from other domain.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the above and below lines of your code?

Comment: Can you post your server response?

Comment: JSONP expects the serve to serve a runnable script. Is the server serving a runnable script?

Comment: @mshaaban have added the server response or JSON data...

Comment: Using **JSONP**, the expected response from server is `callbackMethod("Inline_JSON");`. So, the key-point here is you need to **inline** your JSON (single line)

Comment: not all api's serve jsonp or are CORS enabled. If neither is true you need to use a proxy to get your data. Being able to open as url in browser is not the same as using ajax as far as security rules

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "http://xxxx.com/zzzz",
                dataType: 'json', 
                success: function (json) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the datatype from 'jsonp' to 'json'

Answer (score 0):

I think your response is a valid JSON string, but not valid JSONp. The p in JSONp stands for "padding". That means the response must be wrapped within a JavaScript function and returned with the content type text/javascript Please see the example below:

```
myCalllbackFunc({ my: "data" });
```

When you use jQuery, the library will pass a callback variable as a query parameter to your back-end. The value defines the name of your callback function.

```
http://your.host/json?callback=fooBarFunc
```

should result into this

```
fooBarFunc({ my: "data" });
```

Cheers,
Peter

BTW: beside JSONp, you could use CORS for cross origin resource sharing :) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: `CORS` isn't really a simple thing that you ***use***...it is dependent on remote server having it enabled or not

Comment: No big difference, if you have to modify the response for JSONp, or set the CORS header. It's a back-end change in any case.

Comment: point being that some people don't realize that it is a back end issue and that unless you control that domain you can't do anything about